# How do I add inline JavaScript to the footer?

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to add third-party JavaScript code at bottom of the every page. I build an module and I am able to add the JavaScript on the head tag, instead of footer.

I am using the following code.

```
function ur_optin_monster_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('ur_form.admin_settings');
  $variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#tag' => 'script',
      '#value' => $config->get('my_js'),
      '#weight' => 400, 
    ],
    'ur_form_js',
  ];
}
```

I also tried changing `'html_head'` to `'html_scripts'`, but it doesn't help. I tried with the *batrik.theme* file, but it gives the following error.

> Error: Call to undefined function drupal_add_js() in bartik_preprocess_html() (line 95 of core/themes/bartik/bartik.theme).

```
function bartik_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('ur_form.admin_settings');
  if ($config->get('my_js')) { 
    drupal_add_js($config->get('my_js'), array('scope'=>'footer'));
  }
}
```

Can you suggest me the correct way to add JavaScript code at the footer of every page?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102242/discussion-on-question-by-user3463733-how-do-i-add-inline-javascript-to-the-foot).

Answer (score 2):

Until [Add support for inline JS/CSS with #attached](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2391025) is resolved, you should add a JavaScript file normally as a library defined in a MYMODULE.libraries.yml and then pass your module's config as Drupal settings from PHP to this JavaScript file.

```
foobar:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/myscript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Then in MYMODULE.module add the JS file and pass the config over to JS.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/foobar';

  // Pass values from PHP to JS.
  $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['MYMODULE']['lorem'] = \Drupal::config('MYMODULE.settings')->get('lorem');
  $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['MYMODULE']['ipsum'] = \Drupal::config('MYMODULE.settings')->get('ipsum');
}
```

Then in the JS file access them like following.

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.MyBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      $('html').once('MyBehavior').each(function() {

        var lorem = settings.MYMODULE.lorem;
        var ipsum = settings.MYMODULE.ipsum;

        // Do whatever you need to do.
        // ...

      });          
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

---

I just found [Inline JavaScript that is in an integration module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#s-inline-javascript-that-is-in-an-integration-module) in the docs. But it also says

> **Using any inline JavaScript is highly discouraged**. If you can use one of the examples above, please consider those before attempting to
>   do this.